# Is it possible to give stakeholder access only to a specific board?

Tags: azure-devops

I have two boards (two teams) inside a project, and I want to give access to one board to 3 stakeholders, and another boaard to other 2 stakeholder.

Is it possible?

Comment: I agree with Andy's suggestion, we can't control the boards in different teams with different visit permissions for several stakeholder. Of course, if you have any good suggestion, you could submit it to the feature request site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services, if you submit it, you could share it here, so other members who have the same request could help you vote it, and if Andy's suggestion is helpful for you, you could accept it as the answer.  Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 2):

No, we cannot achieve that.

> As a stakeholder, you can access the backlog, task and Kanban boards,
>   work items and manage approvals for Releases.

That means the stakeholder can access all the boards for all the teams.

However if you want to restrict the specific stakeholders to **view / edit / mamage** the work items under specific team backlog or boards, then you can [Define area and iteration paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

> Area paths allow you to group work items by team, product, or feature
>   area. Whereas, iteration paths allow you to group work into sprints,
>   milestones, or other event-specific or time-related period. Both these
>   fields allow you to define a hierarchy of paths.
>
> You define area and iteration paths for a project. Teams can then
>   choose which paths are used to support their backlog and other Agile
>   tools.
>
> **Source here : [About area and iteration paths (aka sprints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=vsts)**

After that you can add the stakeholders as the member of the specific team accordingly.

Then you can set the permissions to restrict the specific stakeholders to view/edit/manage the specific node.

Thus, the specific stakeholders cannot see the work items under the specific area path in backlog or board.

[image]